# how to disable AppWithUsageAccess in my application i have enabled AppWithUsageAccess but programmaticaly not disable how to disable any idea

Tags: java, android

this code is enabled the AppWithUsageAccess but not disable automatic

```
UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 10, time);

            if (stats == null || stats.isEmpty()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: any idea to off programmatic AppWithUsageAction state change